# I'm not able to route to another page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
import './App.css';
import CreateBug from './CreateBug';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/createBug" element={<CreateBug/>}/>
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
          BUGHOUND
        </p>
           <Button variant="contained" >Create a bug</Button>
      </header>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I got this error :

> Uncaught Error: [header] is not a <Route>

I am not able to route to next page/component. path has to be changed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your `header` element should not be a child of Router. Try this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
          BUGHOUND
        </p>
        <Button variant="contained" >Create a bug</Button>
      </header>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/createBug" element={<CreateBug/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Onclick of that button, how do I route to this component?

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests everything inside `<Routes>` must be wrapped with `<Route><header className="App-header"></Route>` or move the Header before `<Routes>` so like this

```
<Router>
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
          BUGHOUND
        </p>
           <Button variant="contained" >Create a bug</Button>
      </header>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/createBug" element={<CreateBug/>}/>
        </Routes>
</Router>
```